# Ajax data crossover between browsers?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, internet-explorer

One of our testers had both Chrome and IE open, working on the same page in the application to compare side-by-side. (This is an ASP.NET MVC project.) She discovered that if she starts an ajax call running in Chrome and then flips to IE and does the same thing, the results she expects in Chrome are actually displaying in IE instead, and nothing happens in Chrome. It's as if the function in IE is intercepting the results.

I didn't even know that was possible. Any advice?

Here's the ajax call. When this is started first in Chrome and then IE, the results I expect in Chrome actually load in IE instead.

```
        $.ajax({
        url: '/Product/Load/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            catalogid: catalogid,
            styleid: styleid,
            shapeid: shapeid,
            editmode: editmode
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Error == null) {
                $('#questionPanel').html(result.ViewString);
                $('#questionPanel').show();
            } else {
                $("#loadingIndicator").hide();
                alert("An error occurred loading this product.");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("An error occurred loading this product");
        }
    });
```

Comment: For that I know, IE should retrieve the result from Chrome (if correctly ended) and it's own result. But with the two browser working at the same time, on the same data, it can be hazardous because you won't know which request ended first.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like cache to me... try the $.ajax() with cache: false

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: We do have cache: false set on all ajax calls because I've had trouble with that in IE before. Even if it was caching, though, isn't that the browser cache? I'm confused how it could be 'crossing over' between the browsers.

Comment: The crossing over sounds really weird, that's why I thought it were cache and a misunderstanding :) I think you have to give us the .NET code for us to help you - or at least describe what it does.

Comment: I added the ajax call. The .NET code just loads a view with a series of dropdown menus. So basically the view I expect to load in Chrome is loading in IE instead.

Comment: Hmm I just don't know - sorry. IE and Chrome have different sessions, so it sounds kind of impossible :) If you don't do anything magical in the .NET end, for example cache the output to a key that is the users IP or so.